# Dell XPS 13 HDMI works on Samsung TV but not on LG

Tags: hdmi, tv, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 which has updated display drivers (so it's not the issue).

It works fine on a Samsung TV (HDMI), but for some very strange reason it is not recognised by the LG TV which just says 'No Signal'.

I know how to toggle between displays etc - so it's not that. The HDMI adapter (of which I have 2) works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

LG TVs are known to have HDMI cable fits. Seems they're very picky in that regard. Usually it's fixed with new cable, preferably of at least good quality and 1.4 compatible.

Also, adapters are known for compatibility issues. They may work fine, but not with all manufacturers or even specific equipment. My recommendation is to not use adapters. But if you must, it's best to try which one works with your TV before you buy one (yeah, I know how that sounds...).

My recommendation is to try new (by which I mean brand new) cable and if you also use adapters try different ones.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is I live in UK and travel to Singapore to make my presentations on this 60" LG TV.

Comment: And I have bought a new Dell adaptor (as the XPS13 does not have an HDMI slot)

The cable has been swapped (and they are high quality) and still no joy.

Thanks for your suggestions and time

Comment: @JohnHowell - Are you sure you bought genuine Dell? Just a question - quite often what you actually buy is "Dell-compatible"(-ish) or flat out fake. Also, adapter might be working perfectly and be genuine and still not working with the TV, as it's the latter that's not really HDMI-compatible...

Comment: Oh, I'm always forgetting: which XPS13 you have? there are at least five generations of this model.

Comment: lt is a Dell XPS 13  L321X

The adaptor is a genuine Dell - purchased from Dell

Thanks for your time folks